# how to use destroy() method of class ComponentRef<C>

Tags: angular

I'm trying to destroy a component using **ComponentRef class** by injecting it to the constructor as **private compRef : ComponentRef**

*It is giving Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for ComponentRef!*

Tried including ComponentRef in the providers array at component level and app.module, but it says type ComponentRef is not assignable to type 'Providers'.

Any help about how to implement ComponentRef to be able to use destroy() method?

Thank you.

Comment: see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45474587/2545680) for the explanation of the destroy method. why do you want to destroy a component?

Comment: @maximus, thanks for your help. I will need to clear all the properties and objects related to that component. I thought destroy() method is a quick and clean way of doing that.

Comment: I see. `destroy` is not actually doing what you think it does. Check my updated answer

Comment: great, thanks for your clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`destroy()` method can be called on the dynamically created components. Here is the simple example:

```
export class SampleComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChild("vc", {read: ViewContainerRef}) vc: ViewContainerRef;

    constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {}

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        const componentFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(BComponent)
        const componentRef = this.vc.createComponent(componentFactory);
        componentRef.destroy(); <-------------------
    }
}
```

You **can't access** the `componentRef` of the component if it wasn't created dynamically.

> I will need to clear all the properties and objects related to that
>   component.

The `destroy` method doesn't actually clear any properties on the component instance. It simply detaches the view from the view container or `applicationRef`, detaches the projected views and updates the state of the view component. It also triggers `destroy` on the child components and embedded views which perform the same set of operations.

Read these articles for more information:

- [Exploring Angular DOM manipulation techniques using ViewContainerRef](https://hackernoon.com/exploring-angular-dom-abstractions-80b3ebcfc02)
- [Here is what you need to know about dynamic components in Angular](https://hackernoon.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e)